# Create new pipeline for TFS on visualstudio.com

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I try to create a new pipeline in visualstudio.com, I don't see the option to get sources from TFS, only from GIT. There is a message saying:

"To create a pipeline for TFVC, BitBucket, or use the old designer, disable the "New YAML pipeline creation experience" preview feature"

Where can I disable the "New YAML pipeline creation experience"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From your account, Click the preview features

[image]

2. Change the preview features from `for me` to `for this account/organization`

[image]

3. Disable the `Build YAML Pipelines`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/navigation/preview-features?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)

Comment: Perfectly explained! Thanks so much!